# How to convert an integer value to a special format

Tags: c#

I have a numeric value. I want to format it like this:

```
input: 500000 $
output: 500.000 $
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by special format? Here, is dot (.) a decimal separator or a thousands separator?

Comment: var txt = new Decimal(value).ToString("C0");  Perhaps.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your question is quite easy to solve and you should be able to do it.

In pseudocode (You are gonna have to write the program):

```
float num
Writeline input number;
read line num;
num = num / 1000;
print num;
```

Comment: _This_ is the accepted answer? "Divide by 1000"? That has _nothing_ to do with number formatting!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle displaying the number the way you want without having to actually change its value.

As long as that dot character is actually a thousands separator in your culture, you can use the format string `##,# $`.

```
var value = 50000;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("##,# $"));
```

- `#` acts as a numeric place holder,
- `,` acts as the separator (this
  particular string can handle larger numbers, the groups are repeated for each "thousand" grouping, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierTh) for more detail on how it works),
- `$` is displayed
  literally.

The output is : `50.000 $` as requested.

Also, because this formatting is culture dependant, it will display correctly if  the program happens to be run in a country that uses a different separator.

---

If `500.000 $` happens to be the "normal" way your culture displays currency, you can use the standard format string `C0`.  This simple formats the number with your culture's default currency format, with 0 decimal places.  This will also automatically adjust for the culture of the person running the application.

---

If you do NOT want these to adjust to the culture format of the user, you can pass an explicit culture to `ToString`.

```
var value = 50000;
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C0", culture));
```

This will display `500 000 €` on my machine, even though the default culture (en-US) would cause it to display `$50,000`